# String to JSON numero grande

Tags: java, json, jsonobject

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
string obj = '{"phonetype":2854327976340,"cat":"WP"}'
Syso(getJSON(obj).phonetype)   =>  works!
obj = '{"phonetype":285432797634011960000,"cat":"WP"}'
Syso(getJSON(obj).phonetype)   =>  Error!


private JSONObject getJSON (value) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    
    return (JSONObject) parser.parse(value)
}
```

Error is :

```
For input string: "285432797634011960000". Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "285432797634011960000"
```

Comment: ¿Y para qué necesitas un campo tipo `Number`? Para ese dato (teléfono) se suele usar un tipo `String`.

Comment: es lo que me devuelve un web service que consumo, ese web service no lo puedo tocar

Comment: Y si lo conviertes en `String` ese dato?

Comment: a mi me llega ya un string, en todo caso tendria q ser el WS que me envie un string pero no tengo acceso a ese código

Comment: el json es un string... el error lo da tu codigo? manejalo como string...

Comment: no hay posibilidad de manejarlo como un string eso me viene de un WS

Answer (score 3):

El problema que tienes aquí es porque `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser` los datos numéricos tiene la limitante de convertirlos a `long`, la mejor opción es cambiar de librería como `jackson` que este tipo de datos lo convertiría a `BigInt` que seria el formato correcto en Java, el cuidado que debes te tener es porque según el largo del numero en Jackson el tipo de dato cambiaria, si por estándar ya tienes un largo de finido te puedes ahorrar comprobar el tipo de dato, pero lo mejor es que el `Json` lo conviertas a un objeto directamente para ahórrate las comprobaciones:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class JsonData {
    private BigInteger phonetype;
    private String cat;

    public BigInteger getPhonetype() {
        return phonetype;
    }

    public void setPhonetype(BigInteger phonetype) {
        this.phonetype = phonetype;
    }

    public String getCat() {
        return cat;
    }

    public void setCat(String cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JsonData{" +
                "phonetype='" + phonetype + '\'' +
                ", cat='" + cat + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

---

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.BigIntegerNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.IntNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.LongNode;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonBigIntTest {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String obj = "{\"phonetype\":285432797634011960000,\"cat\":\"WP\"}";

        convertToTreeNode(obj);

        convertToObject(obj);

    }

    public static void convertToTreeNode(String json) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);

        System.out.println(node.get("cat"));

        System.out.println(node.get("phonetype") + " : " + node.get("phonetype").getClass());
        if (node.get("phonetype") instanceof BigIntegerNode) {
            BigIntegerNode value = (BigIntegerNode) node.get("phonetype");
            System.out.println(value.bigIntegerValue());
        } else if (node.get("phonetype") instanceof LongNode) {
            LongNode value = (LongNode) node.get("phonetype");
            System.out.println(value.longValue());
        } else if (node.get("phonetype") instanceof IntNode) {
            IntNode value = (IntNode) node.get("phonetype");
            System.out.println(value.intValue());
        }
    }

    public static void convertToObject(String json) throws IOException {
        JsonData jsonData = mapper.readValue(json, JsonData.class);
        System.out.println(jsonData);
    }
}
```

---

Ejemplos:

```
Json1: {"phonetype":2854327976340,"cat":"WP"}
Salida de datos
"WP"
2854327976340 : class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.LongNode
2854327976340

JsonData{phonetype='2854327976340', cat='WP'}

_____________________________________________________________________________

    
Json2: {"phonetype":285432797634011960000,"cat":"WP"}
Salida de datos
"WP"
285432797634011960000 : class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.BigIntegerNode
285432797634011960000

JsonData{phonetype='285432797634011960000', cat='WP'}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero la clase JsonData en tu ejemplo es de 2 campos solo, pero lo que me devuelven no son solo 2 atributos, son como 100, tendria q hacer el mapeo a los 100 atributos o hay alguna forma mas corta?

Comment: @sirdaiz dependería de tus requerimientos si los necesitas todos o solo unos pocos, si son unos pocos lo que debes hacer es utilizar la propiedad `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);` con esta propiedad `Jackson` ignora los atributos que no están declarados en la clase para evitar que falle y si necesitas todos los campos puedes utilizar la siguiente web: https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo esta web te permite pegar un json completo y generar las clases java partir de este puede que tengas que ajustar alguna propiedad pero en general esta bien.